# How to insert values from another table

Tags: ms-access, insert

I am inserting two values to a table, one from another table and the other from form control but I am getting an error.

```
 sqlstr = "INSERT INTO partylinks ( accountid, partyid ) values(Select max(accountsinfo.accid) FROM accountsinfo,2 )"
                cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sqlstr, con, tra)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: `Select max(accountsinfo.accid)` will not work as a value and it is probably a very bad idea anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You don't use the `VALUES` syntax if you are `SELECT`ing

Try:

```
sqlstr = "INSERT INTO partylinks (accountid, partyid) Select max(accountsinfo.accid),2 AS partyid FROM accountsinfo"
```

Comment: I still have strong reservations about Max. It sounds very like the OP is looking for the last created Id, which is going to be disastrous.